# GAS UI not displaying

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently learning about the google Ui Service

I have a standalone google script (not part of any document) and in that script I have the following code which I took from [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service).

```
function demoUI() {
  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('An improved GUI');

  var mygrid = myapp.createGrid(3, 2);
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 0, myapp.createLabel('Name:'));
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 1, myapp.createTextBox());
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 0, myapp.createLabel('Age:'));
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 1, myapp.createTextBox());
  mygrid.setWidget(2, 0, myapp.createLabel('City'));
  mygrid.setWidget(2, 1, myapp.createTextBox());

  var mybutton = myapp.createButton('Press me');
  var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel();
  mypanel.add(mygrid);
  mypanel.add(mybutton);
  myapp.add(mypanel);
  return myapp;
}
```

The problem is that when I run the script, nothing gets displayed.

I tried adding this script to a google doc (document, not spreadhseet), same again, when I run the script, nothing gets displayed.

I must be misunderstanding something, but no idea what it is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Crouz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the UI within Google Docs you need to put it into a [dialog or sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs). For instance `DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(myapp, 'My Dialog')`. To serve the UI outside of the Google Doc, rename the function `doGet()` to make it a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps).

Answer (score 0):

You should replace:

```
return myapp;
```

by:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.show(myapp);
```

At last, you should have:

```
function demoUI() {
  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('An improved GUI');

  var mygrid = myapp.createGrid(3, 2);
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 0, myapp.createLabel('Name:'));
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 1, myapp.createTextBox());
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 0, myapp.createLabel('Age:'));
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 1, myapp.createTextBox());
  mygrid.setWidget(2, 0, myapp.createLabel('City'));
  mygrid.setWidget(2, 1, myapp.createTextBox());

  var mybutton = myapp.createButton('Press me');
  var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel();
  mypanel.add(mygrid);
  mypanel.add(mybutton);
  myapp.add(mypanel);


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.show(myapp);
 }
```